# What is the African board game in this picture?

Tags: identify-this-game

What is the name of the board game in the picture below?

Any article/document about the game would be very appreciated.

[image: board game]

Answer (score 15):

I'm pretty sure it's [ZAMMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zamma):

I'm seeing the 9 x 9 board there, and two different types of pieces equivalent to black and white.  Also, I'm no expert, but that scene does look a bit North African to me.

From [this page](http://mlwi.magix.net/bg/zamma.htm): **"When played in the Sahara, the men are represented by short sticks, whilst the women are pieces of camel dung."**  That certainly looks like what's going on in the picture, unpleasant though it sounds!  I don't think camel dung meeples will catch on outside Africa...

Comment: @John The content from the old page was [available on archive.org still](https://web.archive.org/web/20120920190359/http://hem.passagen.se/melki9/zamma.htm), and there was a new page with exactly the same content.